# Turning off XON/XOFF when SSHing via PuTTY

Tags: server, command-line, ssh, 9.10, putty

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 9.10 on a rented dedicated server.

When I ssh to it using PuTTY (on a Windows machine), I find it responds to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as XON/XOFF transmission control (i.e. the terminal freezes everytime I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> until I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>).

This hasn't been a problem on other remote servers, and I realise I don't really have much idea about how this is determined. Is this something that is negotiated at the start of the terminal session, something that is set by the choice of terminal emulation (TERM=xterm, if that helps) or - as I suspect - some setting on the server I am not aware of.

How do I tell Ubuntu that it is 2011, and no-one has terminals that rely on XON/XOFF any more?

Comment: I still use xon/xoff.  I often view log streams from webservers, looking for exceptions and errors.  It is very convenient to stop the terminal and then scroll back to view the error.  Think of it as a terminal tivo (without the skipahead).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [a SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/124845/can-you-disable-the-ctrl-s-xoff-keystroke-in-putty), just run this once connected:

```
echo "stty -ixon" >> ~/.bash_profile
reset
```

And that should fix it.

(Updated to correct option)